# C++ how to call IR function

Tags: function, llvm, call, llvm-ir

I have a C++ file, which hassome functions, such as:`int myMax(int a,int b)`, and compile it to a llvm IR. Now I want to operate the IR in another C++ file, I don't know how to call the function(such as: myMax)in my C++ file.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile IR to an object file for your platform (using `llc`).  This object file is like any other object file produced by, say, a C++ compiler. So you can call it from your C++ code.

More concretely. You compile a file with `int myMax(int a, int b)` into some object file, say `mymax.o`. Your "user" C++ code needs to:

1. See the declaration of `myMax` by including the appropriate header, or just declaring the function prototype.
2. Link to `mymax.o` to have the implementation in the final executable.

---

Alternatively, you can use the existing JIT capability of LLVM to JIT the IR module in your C++ code and then use `getPointerToFunction` to access it.